# What referenceContainer are the product page breadcrumbs in?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, containers

I want to add a banner to the top of all the product pages. So far I've added

`<referenceContainer name="columns.top">`

to the default.xml that links to my template file. This displays the banner, but its under the breadcrumbs and is screwing with the block titles on some of the static pages.

**Where should I reference to have my banner above the breadcrumbs, but below the navigation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breadcrumbs block is a child block of the `page.top` container which is itself placed just after `header.container`

It is declared under `Magento\Theme\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
     ...
     <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

To place your block before the breadcrumbs you can do the following:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="My\Block\Class" name="my_block" before="breadcrumbs" />
</referenceContainer
```